# Reconstruction of continuous f(x) $\in$ [0,2] and with cusp at $\sqrt2$, with samples at all rational x, only

Tags: real-analysis

If you have continuous $f(x)$ defined over the real x interval $[0,2]$ as follows:

$f(x) = x, \hspace{2.4cm}  0 \leq x < \sqrt2$

$f(x) = (2\sqrt2 - x), \hspace{0.5cm} \sqrt2 \leq x \leq 2 $

This creates a cusp in $f(x)$ at $x = \sqrt2$, where $f(\sqrt2) = \sqrt2$.

Suppose I do not have the above specification for $f(x)$ in the interval, but instead have the values for $f(x)$ at all rational $x$ within the interval.

Would I be able to derive the cusp being at exactly $\sqrt2$?

I am thinking the answer is yes, because the rationals are a dense subset of the reals and so $x=\sqrt2$ is the limit point of a sequence of rational $x$ values, from either direction along $x$.  $f(x)$ is continuous, so $f(x)$, for rational $x$, is a dense subset of $f(x)$, for real $x$, I think. So, if we look at the sequence of rational $x$, with its limit point at $\sqrt2$, and look at the sequence $f(x)$ that corresponds to that $x$ sequence, then the value of $f(\sqrt2)$ is the limit point of that sequence of $f(x)$. That limit point of that sequence of $f(x)$ should end up being $\sqrt2$. In this way, we can derive $f(x)$ for any real $x$ and see (induce?) that the cusp is at $x=\sqrt2$. Or, is that reasoning incorrect or, is there a better or clearer reason why the answer to being able to derive the cusp being at exactly $\sqrt2$ is yes, if indeed the answer is yes?